# Am I changing the vector basis correctly? Thanks.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I have read some of the other questions here on change of basis, but I am still not sure if I am solving my problem correctly. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me. Thanks.

Consider $S_1, S_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. The local coordinate bases for $S_1$ are $\{\mathbf{e}_2,-\mathbf{e}_1\}$, and for $S_2$ are $\{\mathbf{e}_1, \mathbf{e}_2\}$, with $\mathbf{e}_i$ the standard bases. Now, consider maps,
$$
\phi_i : S_i \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2
$$
$$
(u_1, v_1) \mapsto u_1\mathbf{\alpha}_2 + v_1\mathbf{\alpha}_3
$$
$$
(u_2, v_2) \mapsto u_2\mathbf{\alpha}_1 + v_2\mathbf{\alpha}_2
$$
where $\alpha_i$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The maps are such that,
$$
\phi_1([0, 1]\times\{0\}) = \phi_2(\{0\}\times[0, 1]).
$$

Next, given the coordinates $[u_1, v_1]^T \in S_1$, I want the transformation map from $S_1$ to $S_2$. My first thought was,
$$
[\alpha_2, \alpha_3]\left[
\begin{array}{c}
u_1\\
v_1
\end{array}\right] =
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
a\\
b
\end{array}\right] = 
[\alpha_1, \alpha_2]\left[
\begin{array}{c}
u_2\\
v_2
\end{array}\right]
$$
and so the matrix representing the transformation from $S_1$ to $S_2$ would be,
$$
[\alpha_1, \alpha_2]^{-1}[\alpha_2, \alpha_3].
$$

However, my teacher's notes indicate that the correct transformation is,
$$
S[\alpha_2, \alpha_3]^{-1}[\alpha_1, \alpha_2]S,
$$
with,
$$
S = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array} \right].
$$
What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you specify? 1) what are $S_i$ (you speak of local coordinate basis of $S_i$ - so those are some tangent subspaces?) 2) $\phi_i$ satisfies some mapping condition - do we assume that $[0,1] \times \{0 \} \subset S_1$ and similarly for $S_2$ ? 3) notation $[\alpha_1 , \alpha_2]$ where $\alpha_i$ are vectors - do you refer to the matrix with columns being $\alpha_i$? (why the comma between them?) 4) you use $[\alpha_1 , \alpha_2]^{-1}$ - does that refer to the inverse matrix? do we assume $\alpha_i$ are linearly independent? 5) what do you mean by transformation from $S_1$ to $S_2$

Comment: @RadekSuchánek Thanks for your comment.
(1) $S_i$ are just open balls in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
(2) Yes, we assume that.
(3) Yes, the $\alpha_i$s are the columns of the matrix.
(4) Yes, we assume that the $\alpha_i$s are pairwise linearly independent.
(5) The problem just says a transition map from $S_1$ to $S_2$. I took it to mean $\psi: S_1 \rightarrow S_2$ such that $\phi_1\circ\psi = \psi\circ\phi_2$, but my interpretation could be incorrect (since we know the correct answer)? Does the correct answer help you in deducing what map is being talked about?